# Convert C# HMAC SHA256 to PHP

Tags: c#, php, sha256, hmac

I've a C# method which I have to convert to PHP. I tried several things, but I still get different results. Unfortunately I cannot change anything on the C# application. It has to be as it is. Maybe one of you could help?

**C#:**

```
static public void Main ()
{
    string StringToSign = "test";
    string Key = "123456";

    //Calculate Signature
    string Signature = CalculateSignature(StringToSign, Key);

    Console.WriteLine ("StringToSign: " + StringToSign);
    Console.WriteLine ("Key: " + Key);
    Console.WriteLine ("Signature Caculated: " + Signature + "\r\n");
}

static private string CalculateSignature(String StringToSign, String Key)
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);

    byte[] KeyHex = StringHexValuesToByteArray(Key);
    byte[] StringToSign_byte = enc.GetBytes(StringToSign);

    //Check Signature
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(KeyHex);
    byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(StringToSign_byte);

    return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "");
}

static public byte[] StringHexValuesToByteArray(string str)
{
    if (str.Length % 2 != 0)
        return null;

    string s = string.Empty;
    byte[] ret = new byte[str.Length / 2];

    for (int run = 0; run < str.Length / 2; run++)
    {
        s = str.Substring(run * 2, 2);
        ret[run] = Convert.ToByte(s, 16);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
public function send() {

    $stringToSign = 'test';
    $key = '123456';

    //Calculate Signature
    $signature = $this->calculateSignature($stringToSign, $key);

    print_r("StringToSign: " . $stringToSign . PHP_EOL);
    print_r("Key: " . $key . PHP_EOL);
    print_r("Signature Caculated: " . $signature . PHP_EOL);
}

private function calculateSignature($stringToSign, $key) {

    // check signature
    $hash = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $key, false));
    return $hash;
}
```

For better understanding, here is the output of the code blocks above:

**C#**

> StringToSign: test
>
> Key: 123456
>
> Signature Caculated:
>   DA3617974490FB780F04F06287BF93B0F24A7F15970471146428B943FFDC7850

**PHP**

> StringToSign: test
>
> GroupKey: 123456
>
> Signature Caculated: 9D2BB116E1DF997FFE8A5139FC1D187F976C19579A138414A112BC2E39020EBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to modify the PHP to make it equivalent to C#**

Change

```
$hash = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $key, false));
```

to

```
$hash = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, hex2bin($key), false));
```

Be sure to check the code will work for non-ASCII characters like `àèéìòù`.

[ideone here](https://ideone.com/5tW6fz).

**If you want to modify the C# code to make it equivalent to PHP**

You are complicating everything:

```
static private string CalculateSignature(String stringToSign, String key)
{
    byte[] key_byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] stringToSign_byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

    //Check Signature
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key_byte);
    byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(stringToSign_byte);

    return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "");
}
```

There is nothing hex. And instead of using `Encoding.GetEncoding(65001)` it is normally better to use `Encoding.UTF8`, because it is clearer for everyone.

Note that there could be problems with the encoding. Try calculating the hmac of something like `àèéìòù` to see which encoding the PHP is using.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change anything on the C# application. It has to be as it is. Actually the key looks like "8A46AA67F474FB3285D3A55F4798EB24BCFF460AF1529F07AD140DB77F579D3CD1A614C8D80A56952F2CB96ED60F8BDE0BCC398C196507008C404BD2DCDFF9D1". I just changed it for testing purposes.

Comment: @ChristianDornbusch Updated the response.